# how to close Modal popup without waiting for ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

I am sending some attachments with email through ajax. But it is taking too much time to send and close the email modal. So i want to know is there any way, so that my modal popup should get closed as soon as i click on send email button and ajax would perform on background without any interruption

```
$.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:url,
           data:data,
           mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false
           success: function(data, xhr, status) {
               $("#demo").modal('hide');
              window.location="abc.html";
           }           
       })
```

Please help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `$("#demo").modal('hide')` place this at the begining of ajax function

Comment: Sudhanshu, what if the ajax request fails? don't you want to keep the modal open, then?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the modal **before**  sending the `AJAX` request. [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) has `beforeSend` handler to perform operation before executing the AJAX request.

Code would look something like this,

```
$.ajax({
           type:"POST",
           url:url,
           data:data,
           mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
           contentType: false,
           cache: false,
           processData: false,
           beforeSend: function () {
                 $("#demo").modal('hide');
            },
           success: function(data, xhr, status) {
                 window.location="abc.html";
           }           
       });
```

Comment: Alok Patel: i tried ur method bt its only hiding the modal bt not reloading the page. Page is reloading only when ajax gets "success". Please give some other suggestions.

Comment: Move page reload code in `beforeSend` too.  Edited the answer.

Comment: Won't the page reload abort the AJAX request?

Comment: @Cerbrus You're right, it will abort the AJAX request in critical case. So this should be avoided.

Comment: So give any solution so that i can send the email with attachments, and do other things  without waiting for response.

Comment: Well, you simply _can not_ change `window.location` while the ajax request is pending.

Comment: @sudhanshubalaiya If you're using AJAX, you at least have to send request once to server to process it.

Comment: so you mean to say that i have to wait for ajax success to continue further and cannot do anything  :(

Comment: Yeah success or error.  You can handle errors in `error: function (e, textStatus)` callback of `.ajax`.

Answer (score -1):

modal box having parameter closable you can use it.

and when you click on submit button then use return false;

it will close your modal box. I hope it will help you

```
                $.ajax({
                url:'',
                cache:'false',
                success:function(html){
                BootstrapDialog.show({
                title: 'Add',
                message: html,
                closable: false,
                onshown: function(dialogRef){
                alphanumeric('');},});}});return false;
```